# undefined reference to curl_global_init, curl_easy_init and other function(C)

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I am trying to use Curl in C.

I visited Curl official page, and copied sample source code.

below is the link:
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/sepheaders.html

when I run this code with command "gcc test.c",

the console shows message like below.

```
/tmp/cc1vsivQ.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0xe1): undefined reference to `curl_global_init'
test.c:(.text+0xe6): undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
test.c:(.text+0x10c): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
test.c:(.text+0x12e): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
test.c:(.text+0x150): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
test.c:(.text+0x17e): undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
test.c:(.text+0x1b3): undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
test.c:(.text+0x1db): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
test.c:(.text+0x1e7): undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
test.c:(.text+0x1ff): undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
```

I do not know how to solve this.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You don't link with the library.

When using an external library you must *link* with it:

```
$ gcc test.c -lcurl
```

The last option tells GCC to link (`-l`) with the library `curl`.

Comment: @Accountantم If there's only a static `curl` library, it will be linked statically. Otherwise if it's dynamic then it will be linked dynamically.

Answer (score 39):

In addition to Joachim Pileborg's answer, it is useful to remember that gcc/g++ linking is sensitive to order and that your linked libraries must follow the things that depend upon them.

`$ gcc -lcurl test.c`

**will fail**, missing the same symbols as before. I mention this because I came to this page for forgetting this fact.

Comment: Could you please tell me why `gcc -lcurl test.c` **will fail** but `gcc test.c -lcurl` worked fine?

Comment: @Lane The `gcc -lcurl test.c` will fail because gcc links the files in order of input, so it cannot reference - for example `curl_global_init` - in files appear after `test.c`.

Comment: Many thanks to this post!!!! This saved my day. After reading this post I have just changed the order of linking libraries and I could able to compile and link successfully.

Comment: the param order is wrong : gcc test.c -lcurl

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem, but i use g++ with a make file.
This is a linker issue.
You need to add option -lcurl on the compiler and on the linker.
In my case on the make file:

```
CC ?= gcc
CXX ?= g++
CXXFLAGS += -I ../src/ -I ./ -DLINUX -lcurl  <- compile option
LDFLAGS += -lrt -lpthread -lcurl      <- linker option
```

Gerard

Answer (score 0):

Depending how bad things are you might need an -L/somewhere in LDFLAGS to let the linker know where the libraries are.  ldconfig is supposed to pick them up and find them on every boot but on a new machine it can take a little prodding, like adding a directory to your /etc/ld.so.conf.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found another line among it : "`libcurl-x86.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'`" which means the lib was 64 bit, while i was compiling for 32 bit.