# Undefined reference to curl_easy_init

Tags: c++, windows, curl, mingw-w64

System Windows 7 64bit, Eclipse Mars + CDT, MinGW 64, curl source https://curl.haxx.se/download.html for Win64 - MinGW64 SSH SSL, have tried other versions with very same linker errors
Code:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
int main(void) {
    CURL * curl;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with linker errors:

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -DCURL_STATICLIB "-IC:\\Source\\curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw64\\include" "-IC:\\Source\\curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw64\\include\\curl" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o main.o "..\\main.cpp" 
g++ -static -Wl,-Map,output.map -o xmlServiceCall.exe main.o -lcurl "-LC:\\Source\\curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw64\\lib64" 
main.o: In function `main':
C:\workspace_mars_cpp\xmlServiceCall\Debug/../main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
C:\workspace_mars_cpp\xmlServiceCall\Debug/../main.cpp:25: undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

14:14:56 Build Finished (took 848ms)
```

Have read dozens of similar questions here, and also on other internets, but they all suggest change linking order or add paths which doesn't help. Where else could I dig to solve this problem?

Comment: How did you build `libcurl.a`?

Comment: I didnt build, it was ready-to-use from download site, it says: all libs of this package are build with MinGW64 compiler

Comment: Can you check which symbols you `libcurl.a` exports? Run `nm libcurl.a` and check if `curl_easy_init` and `curl_easy_cleanup` are on the list

Comment: Hmm.. it only says "File format not recognized" on ~30ish *.o files, does it mean the library file could be corrupted?

Comment: These days the file format could be a 64 vs. 32 bit problem.  That gets ironed out eventually, I remember 32 vs 16.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [undefined reference to curl\_global\_init, curl\_easy\_init and other function(C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476196/undefined-reference-to-curl-global-init-curl-easy-init-and-other-functionc)