# Curl error while compiling program

Tags: curl

I am building project using mingw32 but while compiling my source code I am getting following error. Pls help in resolve this issue as I am stuck in between.

```
CMakeFiles\ssd_wv.dir/objects.a(wvdecrypter.cpp.obj):wvdecrypter.cpp:(.text+0x1f86): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_global_init'
CMakeFiles\ssd_wv.dir/objects.a(wvdecrypter.cpp.obj):wvdecrypter.cpp:(.text+0x1f8c): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_init'
CMakeFiles\ssd_wv.dir/objects.a(wvdecrypter.cpp.obj):wvdecrypter.cpp:(.text+0x1fab): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
CMakeFiles\ssd_wv.dir/objects.a(wvdecrypter.cpp.obj):wvdecrypter.cpp:(.text+0x2047): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_slist_append'
CMakeFiles\ssd_wv.dir/objects.a(wvdecrypter.cpp.obj):wvdecrypter.cpp:(.text+0x2a03): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_perform'
CMakeFiles\ssd_wv.dir/objects.a(wvdecrypter.cpp.obj):wvdecrypter.cpp:(.text+0x2a21): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_cleanup'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you read these articles mentioned below?

They seem to deal with your issue.
Try to check your libs/includes, looks like you need to include **DCURL_STATICLIB** and/or some other dependencies before compiling. As much as I can see, some packages are missing for your C++ *decrypting tool*.

[undefined-reference-to-curl-easy-init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678150/undefined-reference-to-curl-easy-init)

[how-do-I-solve-these-libcurl-linking-errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485081/how-do-i-solve-these-libcurl-linking-errors#13356638)

Comment: probably just needs to add `-lcurl` to the compiler or linker